# PHP Date, International month names?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strtotime With Different Languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988536/strtotime-with-different-languages)
>   [Get list of localized months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228887/get-list-of-localized-months)

I get the date time out of my database and format it like so:

```
$row['datetime'] = date('jS F Y',strtotime($row['datetime']));
```

This will put in a format:

```
28th March 2012
```

How can I localise the names of the months, so for french users it would display Mars instead of March?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `setlocale` and `strftime` to get a localized version of the date string.

Example from PHP Docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php :

```
/* Set locale to Dutch */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

/* Output: vrijdag 22 december 1978 */
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978));

/* try different possible locale names for german as of PHP 4.3.0 */
$loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
echo "Preferred locale for german on this system is '$loc_de'";
```

Comment: But notice that [`setlocale` sets the locale process wide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes) (causing unexpected behavior with multiple threads when using multi-threading). Thread safe alternative: [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

Answer (score 1):

Facile, utilise [strftime](http://php.net/strftime) et [setlocale](http://php.net/setlocale).

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf-8'); // ou LC_TIME
echo strftime('%A');
"lundi"
```

Fais attention a utiliser la version utf-8 si tu attends une sortie unicode, sinon, la version normale te donnera du iso-8859-1(5).

In English for the rest of the community, `strftime` respects the locale set, and uses the glibc (in the background). If `date` will always return english `strftime` will respect the `setlocale` and give you the expected output in your language.

Comment: English please. this is an **english** site...

Comment: pardon my French, it was so tempting.

Comment: This doesnt work just shows it in numbers, setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf-8');
     $row['datetime'] = strftime($row['datetime']);