# php - how can I output date in russian locale

Tags: php

I have the following date: `18/07/2013`. I want it to be output in the following format 18 July 2013, where `July` should be replaced with Russian name of the month. So here is what I do:
1) Make timestamp out of the string `18/07/2013`.
2) Set russian locale `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf-8');`
3) Format time using `strftime("%d %B %Y", date)`;
Yet it outputs `18 July 2013` without substituting `July` with Russian name for the month. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486658/php-date-international-month-names

Comment: setlocale(): Returns the new current locale, __or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform__, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid... are you testing the return value from setlocale()?

Comment: @MarkBaker, you're right, it returns FALSE. How to test if the locale is not installed or the category name is invalid?

Comment: On Linux, a `locale -a` will return a list of available locales

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Windows. But I guess that this locale is not available.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to achieve the same result in Spanish was define two arrays, $patterns for the names in English and $replacements with equivalent names in Spanish and call preg_replace function passing them as first and second parameters and the result of formatted date as the third parameter.

This is the function I built:

```
function MonthToSpanish($str, $three = false)
{
    $months = array(
        '/January/', '/February/', '/March/',
        '/April/', '/May/', '/June/', '/July/',
        '/August/', '/September/', '/October/', '/November/', '/December/',
        '/Jan/', '/Apr/', '/Aug/', '/Dec/',
    );
    $meses = array(
        'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio',
        'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre',
        'Ene', 'Abr', 'Ago', 'Dic',
    );
    $res = preg_replace($months, $meses, $str);
    if ($three) {
        $res = str_replace('Mayo', 'May', $res); 
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Hope you'll find it sort of useful.

Answer (score 0):

If Intl extension is installed you can use the MessageFormatter doing your format and possible grammar differences

Example: http://php.budgegeria.de/zrffntr-sbeznggre

PHP Doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.messageformatter.php

If you don't need whole sentences you also can use the IntlDateFormatter: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php